# Is it possible run a docker container multiple times with different arguments?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to figure out if is possible to run an application multiple times using different argument.

I developed my application using .Net, and so far I've executed all the instances using Ubuntu service like:

```
[Unit]
Description=swp %I

[Service]
Environment=ENV=PRODUCTION
Type=simple
User=foo
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /opt/swp/app.dll %i
WorkingDirectory=/opt/app
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
```

Where `%I` is the argument which I pass when I start the service like:

```
sudo systemctl start app@argument1.service
sudo systemctl start app@argument2.service
sudo systemctl start app@argument3.service
```

So I have three instances of the application which run with different logic, based on the argument provided.

How can I replicate the same using Docker?

Comment: Take a look at the [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/). Most of the options in your service file map to some `docker run` options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely possible to do using docker.  The first step you will have to take is to modify your application from using command-line arguments to accepting environment variables.  After this docker [provides an easy method of using environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

**Docker Run**

For example you can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key, just like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE

```
docker run -e DEBUG=1 web python console.py
```

**ENV_FILE**

Or you could make use of an env file.  The example below shows an env_file setting the NODE_ENV environment variable to 'test'

```
$ cat ./Docker/api/api.env
NODE_ENV=test
```

**Docker Compose**

Just like with docker run -e, you can set environment variables on a one-off container with docker-compose run -e

```
docker-compose run -e DEBUG=1 web python console.py
```

You can also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers) for more examples.

If it is not possible or too inconvenient to modify your program to accept environment variables you can easily and an [ARG in your dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935807/how-to-define-a-variable-in-a-dockerfile) to modify how your [CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) is run on startup.

Answer (score 6):

The way to do it on Docker is to use a `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` couple.

[The table in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) is maybe the more convenient way to understand it and is way better than a long description.

But in short, when you are using the ["parameters" form of `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) you can act on the `ENTRYPOINT` of your container and so the executable that it is going to run.

Here is a really simplified form of what you could do with your existing application, just removing the `echo` in the `ENTRYPOINT` of this dummy example should lead you to your desired behaviour already:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "/usr/bin/dotnet", "/opt/swp/app.dll"]
## This would be the default service, 
## if we run the container without any parameter
CMD ["app@argument1.service"]
```

1. Running it without argument:

   ```sh
   docker run 31f3db535473 
   /usr/bin/dotnet /opt/swp/app.dll app@argument1.service
   ```
2. Running it with the second service as an argument:

   ```sh
   docker run 31f3db535473 app@argument2.service
   /usr/bin/dotnet /opt/swp/app.dll app@argument2.service
   ```
3. Running it with the third service as an argument:

   ```sh
   docker run 31f3db535473 app@argument3.service
   /usr/bin/dotnet /opt/swp/app.dll app@argument3.service
   ```