# How can I use a variable inside a Dockerfile SHELL instruction?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Inside my Dockerfile:

```
ENV ENV_NAME=dev_env


RUN conda create -n ${ENV_NAME} python=3.8 pip
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "${ENV_NAME}", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

This would cause error which says ${ENV_NAME} is not a virtual environment name.
I would like to know how I can use a variable in a SHELL instruction.
I tried to follow [How can I use a variable inside a Dockerfile CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454470/how-can-i-use-a-variable-inside-a-dockerfile-cmd) , but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: The SHELL is set and used at build time (for RUN statements in the Dockerfile). So it doesn't make much sense to try to change it at run-time. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @HansKilian I'm trying to install Anaconda in Docker image, init it in bash, create a conda virtual environment, and then activate this newly created conda environment (as in the SHELL line). I'm trying to use a env variable ENV_NAME as the conda environment's name. I'm following this: https://tcoil.info/run-conda-from-virtual-environment-inside-docker-and-start-jupyterlab-with-trading-and-ml-libraries/

Comment: You might be looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770027/5362795) but I have not tried it for `SHELL`, it works for `RUN`.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image contains a fixed version of some single application.  That means you don't need to make every possible thing parametrizable; just pick a name and use it.

```sh
# do not set ENV ENV_NAME=...
RUN conda create -n env python=3.8 pip
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

(If you can use plain `pip install` without a Conda wrapper, that's even easier: don't create a virtual environment and don't bother changing `SHELL`, just `pip install` things into the image's "system" Python.)